# Regular Expression extract in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data like

```
A8
SS4
M9
```

I need to extract all alphabets from this data using

```
REGEX_EXTRACT
```

My Pig Statement is as below

```
A = load 'data';
B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'\\*[^0-9]',1);
dump B;
```

however I get null as my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**Option1:**

```
A = load 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'(.*[^0-9])',1);
DUMP B;
```

**Option2:**

```
A = load 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'(^[A-Za-z]+).*',1);
DUMP B;
```